# How to display menu in adobe business catalyst?

Tags: menu, adobe, business-catalyst

Sorry if my tone is not good, 
How to display top menu in Adobe Business Catalyst.

**Example:**

My custom menu code is given below. Instead of this, I want to display menu created by adobe business catalyst.

```
<ul class="main_menu">
    <li class="current"><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="case-study.html">Case Studies</a></li>
    <li><a href="training.html">Traning</a></li>
    <li><a href="coaching.html">Coaching</a></li>
    <li><a href="local-group.html">Local groups</a></li>
    <li><a href="deal.html">Deals</a></li>
    <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="gear.html">Gear</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
```

I am using this {tag_menugroup} to display menu. but menu is not displaying.

Comment: If I use {tag_menugroup} it display same text like "{tag_menugroup}"

Answer (score 0):

The tag you're using should only be used within custom layouts for menu version 2.

For inserting a dynamic menu to a template use you should instead 
use {module_menu,ID#} 
or for a more customisable version use  {module_menu, version="2", menuId="5475", moduleTemplateGroup="Default"}

Sources: 
http://kb.worldsecuresystems.com/134/bc_1345.html#main_Menu_Modules
http://helpx.adobe.com/business-catalyst/partner/menu-module-v2.html